# Website link loading about:blank page

Tags: html, coldfusion, href

```
<td><a href="http://#trim(website)#" target="_blank">                                    
<cfoutput>#trim(details.webURL)#</cfoutput></a></td>
```

When clicking on the above link on the UI it just loads an about:blank web page.

The website themselves are stored in the db such as www.example.com

Any ideas?

Comment: `trim(website)` needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Are you ready for it?

```
<cfoutput>
    <a href="http://#trim(website)#" target="_blank">                                    
    #trim(details.webURL)#
</cfoutput>
```

You had a variable that isn't wrapped in a `cfoutput`. You are opening a blank link.